# Tar not working from cronjob

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron

I have a python script that backups the sql database when run.

It works flawlessly when i ruin it manually but when it does not run the tar and rm command!

before the backup i run the mysqldump command ofcourse and then after i run this. This is the part of the script that deals with the backup

```
os.system('tar -cvzf Backup_' + formt + '.tar.gz ' + 'sql_Backup_' + formt + '.sql')
os.system('rm ' + 'sql_Backup_' + formt + '.sql')
```

in the cronjob i have

```
# Python SQL Backup Script
00 23 * * 07 sudo /usr/bin/python /home/user/scripts/SQLbackup.py
```

When i run this from the shell itself it runs fine
sudo python /home/user/scripts/SQLbackup.py

but the cronjob does NOT. it only runs the script and creates the sql file and thats it. It doesnt compress it and it does not remove the sql file after compressing either.

i added this to the sudoers file

```
root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/tar
sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/tar
```

and still NOTHING. I put both root and sudo just to be 100 percent sure.

Keep in mind: It runs perfect manually but does NOT run from crontab fully.

Comment: The result email says?

Comment: what result email? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: The one that crond sends for every single cron job that produces output via stdout or stderr.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it doesnt send me any email. and the cronjob does not produce any output. it just runs the backup, runs tar and thats it

Comment: That's not what your question says.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams where in my question do you see it say that it emails me or that it prints out an output to the screen?....its a cronjob, it doesnt print anything to the screen

Comment: Where do you think any Python traceback would go?

Comment: i dont know, the point is it doesnt print anything to the screen. even when i run the script manually it doesnt print anything it just does what it has to do and thats it

Comment: That's because when you run it manually, it works.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you know the solution to why it doesnt when it runs from crontab?

Comment: Not without the traceback. Which would be in the email.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams im sorry but i dont get any email so i have nothing to say about that

Comment: Did you check root's mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that `$PATH` isn't set correctly when the script is run from crontab which than causes the script to not find the specified binaries.

Also check that the script is executed in the right directory.

Modify the script to include the full path to `tar` and `rm` and test if it works better:

```
os.chdir('/path/to/where/sqlfile/resides')
os.system('/usr/bin/tar -cvzf Backup_' + formt + '.tar.gz ' + 'sql_Backup_' + formt + '.sql')
os.system('/bin/rm ' + 'sql_Backup_' + formt + '.sql')
```

Note that `tar` usually is installed in `/usr/bin` but that can differ between different unix flavours.

Comment: ok, can you check the path of "tar" by running "which tar" in the terminal and set that path in the script?

Comment: What happens when you update the script to have the full and correct path to tar (/bin/tar) ?

Comment: it still doesnt compress the .sql file

Comment: Can it be some other problem with the command when it is run from cron? Maybe it does not find the .sql file since it isn't specified with the full path? Try adding "os.chdir('/path/to/sqlfile')" before the tar command.

Comment: Great! Good thing that you got it to work :) I will update my answer with info about os.chdir().